# Uploading an mp3 file with no backend

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm making a music visualizer, and it's functional if the mp3 file is in the repository. So any songs it plays have to already be downloaded by me. I want to create kind of a drag and drop option where users can put mp3 files and then watch them being played. However, if at all possible, I'd like to avoid building an entire backend just for this one feature.

Is there a way to temporarily store a user file, which disappears on refresh?

Comment: Getting a file into the client, easy. Getting a file into server, impossible without some active component that is ready to receive it. For a music visualiser, it is probably enough that your client has the file, no?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47584467/6901876
This answer deals with the actual uploading, handling, and playing of the mp3 file, you would just have to add your own functionality for the drag-and-drop part of it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the `FileReader` API, which allows you to work with files in JavaScript after the user chooses them from a file picker. You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Googling "JavaScript FileReader sound" returns a ton of results, including:

- [JavaScript / HTML5 audio: play mp3 file loaded by user via file selector in Android Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20585899/873165)
- [JavaScript Play Uploaded Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28619550/873165)
- [Play audio local file with html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38265242/873165)
- [decode & play a song using html5 file api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25232966/873165)